# Select count distinct months between two dates from many date registries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the month count between all the registries, but case a month from a year have been counted before, it cannot be counted again.
If the month is from another year, it can be counted.
**Example:**

```
#--|Begin date|--|End Date---|
______________________________
#--|2014-01-01|--|2014-05-01-| 01 to 05 = 5 months
#--|2014-07-01|--|2014-07-31-| 1 month
#--|2014-08-01|--|2015-01-01-| 01/2014 to 01/2015 = 6 months
```

**Total months count from the example:**
5+1+6 == 12 months
 How could I get this count using sql?

Comment: So those dates are in DD/MM/YYYY format? In other words the first 2 #s are the day and the 2nd 2 #s are the month? Also are these actual date fields or are they stored as strings?

Comment: They are in the default format in my database, yyyy-mm-dd. I've fixed it in the example, sorry and thanks

Comment: Do you need the counts row by row or just the grand total of 13? Do you expect 3 rows of output or 1 row of output?

Comment: I just need the count total, one row.

Comment: I've updated it for better understandment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this will get you what you want:

```
select sum(mo_between)
from(
select begin_date, end_date, case when date_format(end_date,'%e') = 1
                                  then 1 + period_diff(date_format(end_date,'%Y%m'),date_format(begin_date,'%Y%m'))
                                  when period_diff(date_format(end_date,'%Y%m'),date_format(begin_date,'%Y%m')) = 0 then 1
                                  else period_diff(date_format(end_date,'%Y%m'),date_format(begin_date,'%Y%m'))
                                  end as mo_between
from tbl) x
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/953e8c/2/0

You can run the following to return it row by row:

```
select begin_date, end_date, case when date_format(end_date,'%e') = 1
                                  then 1 + period_diff(date_format(end_date,'%Y%m'),date_format(begin_date,'%Y%m'))
                                  when period_diff(date_format(end_date,'%Y%m'),date_format(begin_date,'%Y%m')) = 0 then 1
                                  else period_diff(date_format(end_date,'%Y%m'),date_format(begin_date,'%Y%m'))
                                  end as mo_between
from tbl
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/953e8c/1/0

This should handle gaps between months, however it will not handle overlapping periods, I don't know if that is present in your data (it's not present in your example).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are really dates, the following might do what you want:

```
select ((year(max(enddate)) * 12 + month(max(enddate))) -
        (year(min(enddate)) * 12 + month(min(enddate)))
       ) + 1       
from example e;
```

That is, just use the min and maximum from the periods and count the months.

Comment: What about if the registries skip a month? I'm going to update the example.

Comment: @BernardoLima . . . Then this won't do what you want.  That's what I said "might".